# Filtering Enabled Only Products

Tags: select

I am absolutely banging my head against the desk at the moment trying to get this to work. Basically I am trying to get a list of Simple IDs that are set as "In stock", with a quantity <= 3 that has a current status of Enabled within a store view "17"

Here is my code at the moment:

```
setCurrentStore($storeId);

$in_stock_counter = 0;
$out_of_stock_counter = 0;
$product_counter = 0;

// Load all products that are in stock, enabled, and with less than 3 qty
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->joinField('is_in_stock','cataloginventory/stock_item','is_in_stock','product_id=entity_id','is_in_stock=1','{{table}}.stock_id=1','inner')
    ->joinField('qty','cataloginventory/stock_item','qty','product_id=entity_id','{{table}}.qtyaddAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', 1) // get all items in stock
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple')) // get all simple items
       ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("lteq" => 3)) // find qty greater then 3 in stock
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status',Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED) // find enabled products - not working?
    ->SetPageSize(10);

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        var_dump($product->getID());
        echo " ";
        var_dump($product->getQty());
        var_dump($product->getStatus());
        echo "\r\n Set eBay Disable";
        echo "
";
        //Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product->getId(), $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
        $out_of_stock_counter++;
        $product_counter++;
    }

echo "------------------------------------------------------------
"; 

// Load all products that are in stock, disabled, and with more than 3 qty
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->joinField('is_in_stock','cataloginventory/stock_item','is_in_stock','product_id=entity_id','is_in_stock=1','{{table}}.stock_id=1','inner')
    ->joinField('qty','cataloginventory/stock_item','qty','product_id=entity_id','{{table}}.qty>3','inner')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
       ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 3))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status',Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED)
    ->SetPageSize(10);

    foreach ($_products as $_product) {
        var_dump($_product->getID());
        echo " ";
        var_dump($_product->getQty());
var_dump($product->getStatus());
        echo "\r\n Set eBay Enable";
        echo "
";
        //Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($_product->getId(), $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        $in_stock_counter++;
        $product_counter++;
    }

echo "------------------------------------------------------------
"; 

echo "\r\n Number of products set to in stock: " . $in_stock_counter . "
";
echo "\r\n Number of products set to out of stock: " . $out_of_stock_counter . "
";
echo "\r\n Total number of products: " . $product_counter;
```

At the moment, it seems that everything has a status of enabled, even though it is disabled within the storeview:

```
string(4) "4027" string(6) "1.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Disable
string(4) "4031" string(6) "1.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Disable
string(4) "4032" string(6) "1.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Disable
string(4) "4033" string(6) "2.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Disable
string(4) "4036" string(6) "1.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Disable
string(4) "4037" string(6) "2.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Disable
string(4) "4039" string(6) "1.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Disable
string(4) "4040" string(6) "2.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Disable
string(4) "4043" string(6) "1.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Disable
string(4) "4044" string(6) "1.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Disable
------------------------------------------------------------
string(4) "4038" string(6) "4.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Enable
string(4) "4064" string(6) "4.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Enable
string(4) "4065" string(6) "5.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Enable
string(4) "4066" string(6) "6.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Enable
string(4) "4067" string(6) "4.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Enable
string(4) "4068" string(6) "9.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Enable
string(4) "4069" string(6) "8.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Enable
string(4) "4111" string(6) "5.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Enable
string(4) "4112" string(6) "4.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Enable
string(4) "4114" string(6) "5.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Enable
------------------------------------------------------------
Number of products set to in stock: 10
Number of products set to out of stock: 10
Total number of products: 20
```

The products above are all set to disabled in the store view, but they are showing as enabled in the code above. No matter what I try, I cannot get a true output of the status.

Answer (score 2):

Just realised this will not work - The status is a "Website" attribute, which means disabling this in one "store view" will disable it for all websites.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer so that the question does not count as unanswered anymore

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `addFieldToFilter('status',Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)`
and add this line after the `SetPageSize`:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
```

**[EDIT]**

if the above does not work try replacing `addFieldToFilter` with `addAttributeToFilter`.
You should not need to filter by store view since the status attribute is global.

But I also realized something.
What you are seeing is are ENABLED products.

Let's take this line:

```
string(4) "4027" string(6) "1.0000" string(1) "1" Set eBay Disable
            |                |                 |         |
            |                |                 |    some static text you print
            |                |         var_dump($product->getStatus());
            |   var_dump($product->getQty());
            |
var_dump($product->getID());
```

So for status you get 1 which means enabled. I think the text `Disable` throws you off, but that's just a static text you print by using `echo "\r\n Set eBay Disable";`

Comment: That will only show "Catalog,Search" items though wont it? I am looking for all "Simples" that are enabled, this could include "Not Visible Individually" items.

Comment: Just tried the above, and I still get the same output - do I need to filter on storeview?

Comment: @JamesSimpson. See my edit to the answer.

Comment: see my updated code above - I am basically trying to find all products that are enabled and have <=3 in stock, if I find them, I disable them using this code.

Likewise i do the opposite after finding products that are greater then 3 and enabling them. In the first instance I am trying to filter out just all the enabled products (to shorten the query). The list i have stated as disabled are already disabled, so when I refresh the query, these ID's shouldn't be in the list

Comment: var_dump($product->getStatus()) is actually "Disabled" on these products in store 17. They are active in the other stores though.

Comment: 4027, 4031, 4032... These are all disabled in the back end of Magento - so shouldn't appear on this list.

Comment: Any other ideas - I'm all out of ideas